# Wordpress PHP grid layout presentation

Tags: php, wordpress, layout, grid

I want to change the layout of a grid of videos on a site. It's Wordpress.

Currently the PHP displays the grid in a 3/2 layout over two rows and then duplicates it depending on how many videos you choose to display.

I understand the code enough to know that we are setting 5, and splitting into 3/2. And i can set it to 6 and split into 3/3 or 4/2.....and so on

But I need to change the layout so we have a row of 3, then 3 but with the first two of the second row stacked on top of each other 1/3rd width and the third 2/3rd width. like below.

[new layout to be acheived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpV4y.jpg)

Current PHP that does the layout: ( I understand that CSS might have to be changed but I can do that)

```
<article class="col-1-<?php if(($i%5==0)||(($i+1)%5==0)){ echo "2"; } else { echo "3"; } ?>" id="post-<?php echo $page->ID; ?>">
```

Full block:

```
<article class="col-1-<?php if(($i%5==0)||(($i+1)%5==0)){ echo "2"; } else { echo "3"; } ?>" id="post-<?php echo $page->ID; ?>">  

                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID); ?>">

                <?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

                    if (has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) ){ ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" width="160" height="90">     

                    <?php } ?>

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <?php if(get_field('looping_thumb_preview', $page->ID)){ ?>
                   <video playinline preload="auto" loop="yes">
                          <source src="<?php echo get_field('looping_thumb_preview', $page->ID); ?>" type="video/mp4">
                          Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                <?php } else if(get_field('looping_thumb', $page->ID)){ ?>

                        <video playinline preload="auto" loop="yes">
                                      <source src="<?php echo get_field('looping_thumb', $page->ID); ?>" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>

                             <?php } else if (has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) ){ ?>

                            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">     

                            <?php } else { ?>

                                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/blank.png" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>">  

                            <?php } ?>

                        <?php } ?>

                            <div class="center-content">

                                 <h1<?php if(get_field('subtitle', $page->ID)){ echo ' class="hassubtitle"';} else { echo ' class="nosubtitle"'; }?>><?php echo $title;?></h1>
                                 <div class="underline"></div>

                                <?php if(get_field('subtitle', $page->ID)) { echo "<h2>" . get_field('subtitle', $page->ID) . "</h2>"; } 

                            ?>

                            </div>

                        </a>

                    </article>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Forgot to add link to current site in dev - http://www.staging1.makefilms.com/

Comment: Your current layout is based only on row-columns and the difference is that the new one will have to have sometimes (on the left) multiple articles in one column. So only altering that if with mods will not do it.

Comment: OK, thanks, do you know how to write that PHP so I can do that?